# Why is wp_list_pages altering $post->ID of the page?

Tags: custom-field, pages, wp-list-pages, child-pages

So I have a template that is used for all pages in a section that has this script to create a menu based off children:

```
<?php
    if($post->ID = 142) {
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1");
    }
    elseif($post->post_parent) {
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&depth=1"); 
    }

    if ($children): ?>
        <ul>
            <li<?php if ( is_page($post->post_parent)) { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Problem is, when this menu is generated (which it does properly), it holds onto the parent page id of 142 and starts outputting content from custom fields as if it were that page. The interesting thing is that I'm calling a `the_title` further down the page and it's returning the correct page title. This problem persists even after `wp_reset_query` and `wp_reset_postdata`.

I just need the page to get its own ID back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your IF statement.

`if($post->ID = 142)`

should be `if($post->ID == 142)` (notice the 2 equals signs)

Otherwise you are just resetting the variable $post->ID to 142